# PhpOffice PhpWord image margin top

Tags: symfony, phpword, phpoffice

I insert an image like this:

```
->addImage('https://image.png',array('alignment' => 'center','marginTop'=>5000,'wrappingStyle'=>'behind'));
```

And i want to margin-top this image from his top element.

Actually this margin is not working and i don't know why

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok i solved using this code:

```
$portada->addImage('image',array('alignment' => 'center','wrappingStyle'=>'behind'));
```